# Split Large CSV or XLSX to Smaller ones with maximum filesize

Tags: python, csv, split

The main purpose of this script creation is the 40mb limit by email. When I schedule reports online, I don't get them in my inbox if they are larger than 40mb. So, I manually download the file, use the script below and then re-send the files. My issues is that I noticed that in the files, the dates are not consistent.

01) I want to sort rows by date and for example have the first file have the earliest dates from the full file.

02) I want to alter the script and split by the expected MB of each file and not rows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import sys
import os

def split(filehandler, delimiter=',', row_limit=70000,
          output_name_template='LARGE EXCEL/OUTPUT/output_%s.csv', output_path='.', keep_headers=True):
    import csv
    reader = csv.reader(filehandler, delimiter=delimiter)
    current_piece = 1
    current_out_path = os.path.join(
        output_path,
        output_name_template % current_piece
    )
    current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w', newline=''), delimiter=delimiter)
    current_limit = row_limit
    if keep_headers:
        headers = next(reader)
        current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i + 1 > current_limit:
            current_piece += 1
            current_limit = row_limit * current_piece
            current_out_path = os.path.join(
                output_path,
                output_name_template % current_piece
            )
            current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w', newline=''), delimiter=delimiter)
            if keep_headers:
                current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
        current_out_writer.writerow(row)

split(open('LARGE EXCEL/FILE.csv', 'r'));
```

Comment: did you consider zipping the csv files? You should get good compression ratios.

Comment: Zipping doesn't help in this case. We are talking about a file that can be 1GB in some cases